# find out only different part of a file over rsync

Tags: rsync

I have a situation where I have a file lets say TEST.csv in a source system. I want to sync that file in my destiation system. Whenever something new is added or some old data is changed in TEST.csv, the file in destination system also gets changed.
The source system only exposed to rsync, so I can not use any other protocol except rsync.
Now I want to get only the changed part in TEST.csv seperately.
How can I do it?

Comment: Was my answer able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to transfer only the changed part of the `TEST.csv` instead of the whole file, yes?
If that is the case, I don't think it is possible to do this. This is straight out of `man rsync`:

`The  rsync remote-update protocol allows rsync to transfer just the differences between two sets of files across the network connection, using an efficient checksum-search algorithm described in the technical report that accompanies this package.`

The key part is `using an efficient checksum-search algorithm` - it runs a checksum against the local and remote file, and if the checksum differs, it transfers the file from source to target. Based on a checksum, there is no way to tell what part of the file has changed and transfer only the differences.

---

What you could do is use a local versioning tool, e.g. `git`, and use that tool to get the diffs between your sync cycles. When you have the diff, you can store it in a file, transfer it via rsync and then use the `patch` utility on the target end to apply this diff to the `TEST.csv`.

`git` is not needed, you could use a simple `diff -u` on the source and a `patch` on the target, but to use diff you have to track an old `TEST.csv` and a new `TEST.csv` with the new changes and then run `diff` against it. With `git`, you simply edit the file with whatever tools you want, and then git uses its internal mechanism to create the correct diffset to the changes. Just don't forget to add and commit the changes after the diff is transferred, so the next cycle can make a clean diff with only its own changes ;-)